# rails scaffold generation and simple foreign key references problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My issue seems to be somewhere in the default generated scaffold forms when using foreign key references in  your model.

I'll detail out the sequence of generations i ran before i got to my problem:

rails generate scaffold Course name:text desc:text url:string slope:integer rating:float

rails generate scaffold Event name:text desc:text eventdate:date course:references

rake db:migrate

..

At this point I go to the courses page and create a new course and save it.  That works fine.

Then I go to the localhost:3000/events/new page and I try to create a new event using the default form:
The form is like this:
name: textbox
desc: textbox
eventdate: [fill in date widget]
course_id: textbox

I fill in the fields with some information and then "1" in the course_id field, and hit save the error returns with something to the effect of:

Error (#xxxxxxxx) Expected, Got String(#xxxxxxxx)    ... Then a stack trace.

So from what I can see I can tell that i don't think it likes the course_id being passed as a string value, but I can't seem to find where in the framework i need to retrieve that value and convert it to an integer.

The bizarre thing is that the integer value entries in the other table have no issues converting, it just seems that the foreign_key reference is giving it problems.

In the past with rails I've never used the "references" type, and I usually created foreign_key's by making them manually in the scaffold, like so the my generation would have course_id:integer instead of course:references.  Then I manually add the belongs_to into the model from that point.

Anyway.  I could go about doing it the old way but I wanted to get some insight into what Rails 3.0 is doing with this "references" type.

Answer (score 0):

i the event model you have a reference to the course object ( course model). when you try to create a new event you have to do it for a specific course. You are getting an error because there is no "course" passed in the form to rails.

what you have to do :
1 -> select the course ( you can use an embedded list into the new_event view)
2 -> fill the form and submit
3 -> it should work

if it doesn't work for you, i will recommand you to use a partial ( new_event_view) in the course_show view and pass to it the id of course and it will work.

PS : There is a lot of ways to do it.